# BST representation of Hash Tables

Tags: hash-tables, binary-search-trees

I'm reading this book [Cracking Coding Interview](https://www.amazon.in/Cracking-Coding-Interview-Programing-Questions/dp/0984782850). In this book author is speaking about BST representation of Hash Tables.

I googled a lot for BST Representation of Hash Table. Code in C++ but didn't find any link or example. Can someone help me with the implementation. I'm really confused how to represend Key-Value pairs on BST. And what if there are collisions etc.

All, I found was comparison b/w BST and HasTables:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996474/why-implement-a-hashtable-with-a-binary-search-tree
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advantages-of-bst-over-hash-table/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the author means by implementing a HashTable as a BST is simply implementing a BST with $insert(), \space delete() \space and \space search()$ with slight modifications

1. The node of the BST would have  the following structure. $Node \space := (Key,Value)$.
2. Insert a key-value pair by performing comparisons on the keys of two different pairs.
3. Avoids nodes with redundant keys  i.e. before insertion, if a node in the BST with the same key value exists, do not insert it. Else if no node with the same key exists, insert the key-value pair.
4. No change in delete function.
5. Search returns $null$ if no node's key matches, else return the value associated with the key which was searched.

Then use these  functions assuming that these perform the corresponding operations on a HashTable.
Using a self-balancing BST would give $O(log\space n)$  time complexity for all the three functions defined above. And iterating through all the key-value pairs would simply mean doing an in-order traversal of the BST.

Comment: Actually, the author says about ability to iterate over keys IN ORDER, so in-order traversal is that she means

Comment: @Bulat Oh right, thanks for the correction. I guess I glanced over the last part of the sentence.